# Python multiprocessing hangs at join

Tags: python, process, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am reading a video file such that out for every 20 frames I'm storing first  frames in Input Queue. Once I get all the required frames in Input Queue, then I run multiple processes to perform some operation on these frames and store the results in output queue. 
But the code always stuck at join, I tried different solutions proposed for such problems but none of them seems to work.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import timeit
import face_recognition
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pool
import multiprocessing
import os

s = timeit.default_timer()

def alternative_process_target_func(input_queue, output_queue):

    while not output_queue.full():
        frame_no, small_frame, face_loc = input_queue.get()
        print('Frame_no: ', frame_no, 'Process ID: ', os.getpid(), '----', multiprocessing.current_process())
        #canny_frame(frame_no, small_frame, face_loc)

        #I am just storing frame no for now but will perform something else later
        output_queue.put((frame_no, frame_no)) 

        if output_queue.full():
            print('Its Full ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
        else:
            print('Not Full')

    print(timeit.default_timer() - s, ' seconds.')
    print('I m not reading anymore. . .', os.getpid())


def alternative_process(file_name):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_name)
    frame_no = 1
    fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    print('Frames Per Second: ', fps)
    print('Total Number of frames: ', length)
    print('Duration of file: ', int(length / fps))
    processed_frames = 1
    not_processed = 1
    frames = []
    process_this_frame = True
    frame_no = 1
    Input_Queue = Queue()
    while (cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            print('Size of input Queue: ', Input_Queue.qsize())
            print('Total no of frames read: ', frame_no)
            end1 = timeit.default_timer()
            print('Time taken to fetch useful frames: ', end1 - start)
            threadn = cv2.getNumberOfCPUs()
            Output_Queue = Queue(maxsize=Input_Queue.qsize())
            process_list = []
            #quit = multiprocessing.Event()
            #foundit = multiprocessing.Event()

            for x in range((threadn - 1)):
                # print('Process No : ', x)
                p = Process(target=alternative_process_target_func, args=(Input_Queue, Output_Queue))#, quit, foundit
                #p.daemon = True
                p.start()
                process_list.append(p)
                #p.join()

            # for proc in process_list:
            #     print('---------------------------------------------------------------', proc.p)

            i = 1
            for proc in process_list:
                print('I am hanged here')
                proc.join()
                print('I am done')
                i += 1

            end = timeit.default_timer()
            print('Time taken by face verification: ', end - start)

            break

        if process_this_frame:
            print(frame_no)
            small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
            rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]
            face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
            # frames.append((rgb_small_frame, face_locations))
            Input_Queue.put((frame_no, rgb_small_frame, face_locations))
            frame_no += 1

        if processed_frames < 5:
            processed_frames += 1
            not_processed = 1

        else:
            if not_processed < 15:
                process_this_frame = False
                not_processed += 1
            else:

                processed_frames = 1
                process_this_frame = True
                print('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

alternative_process('user_verification_2.avi')
```

Answer (score 4):

As the documentation on [`Process.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) says, *hanging* (or *"blocking"*) is exactly what is expected to happen:

> Block the calling thread until the process whose `join()` method is
>   called terminates or until the optional timeout occurs.

`join()` stops current thread until the target process finishes. Target process is calling `alternative_process_target_func`, so the problem is obviously in that function. It never finishes. There may be more than one reason for that.

### Problem 1

`alternative_process_target_func` runs until `output_queue.full()`. What if it is never full? It never ends? It is really better to determine the end some other way, e.g. run until the input queue is empty.

### Problem 2

`input_queue.get()` will block if the input queue is empty. As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get) says:

> Remove and return an item from the queue. If optional args block is true and timeout is None (the default), block if necessary until an item is available.

You are running multiple processes, so do not expect that there is something in input just because `output_queue.full()` was False a moment ago, and because input size is the same as output size. A lot could have happened in the meantime.

What you want to do is:

```
try:
    input_queue.get(False)  # or input_queue.get_nowait()
except Empty:
    break  # stop when there is nothing more to read from the input
```

### Problem 3

`output_queue.put((frame_no, frame_no))` will block if there is no room in the output to store the data.

Again, you are assuming that there is room in output, just because you checked `output_queue.full()`  a few moments ago, and because input size is equal to output size. Never rely on such things.

You want to do the same thing as for input:

```
try:
    output_queue.put((frame_no, frame_no), False)
    # or output_queue.put_nowait((frame_no, frame_no))
except Empty:
    # deal with this somehow, e.g.
    raise Exception("There is no room in the output queue to write to.")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. What I don't understand here is, If I use try except to read from input queue and add a print statement there, it does not print out all values that are in Input Queue, after getting a few values from Input queue the program stops but actually it should print all values in that try block.

Comment: If I use input_queue.get(timeout=1), it gets all the values that are in input queue and terminates the program successfully, but without timeout i.e. by using input_queue.get(False), after getting some initial values it terminates all the processes. I am unable to understand this behavior.

Comment: @Muhammadhassan Well, you are adding items into the input queue **after** the processes which read from it have been started. So, if reading from the queue is faster than writing to them, of course they will exhaust them and stop. That means you need a different way to determine when to stop and not what I have given you. The timeout may be good enough, depending on what you expect.

Comment: No I'm not adding the items into input queue after the processes have started. The "if not ret" condition makes sure that. However, if instead of queue I use Manager.Queue, the code runs as expected. But I don't know why is it so?

Comment: Hi, what if I set the max size of the Queue? Since it is FIFO, will it release the first-in items during putting items when the queue is full?

Comment: @GoingMyWay As [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue) says, _"Insertion will block once this size has been reached, until queue items are consumed."_ Therefore, you will be able to read from a queue which is full, but writing to it will block until something is removed from it.

Comment: That's great, one can get nearly all the answers via reading the docs. Patience is really important.